# Observer not working - Trying to catch completed sales order - Magento 2.1 EE

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer

Magento 2.1 EE

I have an observer looking to observer "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action".

I can't see what I am missing.  Comparing to all the other posts and my other observers, I don't see why this shouldn't work.

events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="wundercarparts_alsobought" instance="Wundercarparts\AlsoBought\Observer\SaveOrderItems" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

SalesOrderItems.php

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;


class SaveOrderItems implements ObserverInterface {

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog */
        protected $logger;

        public function __construct(
                \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface
        ) {
                $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
        }

        /**
         * This is the method that fires when the event runs.
         *
         * @param Observer $observer
         */
        public function execute( Observer $observer ) {
                $orderId = $observer->getData('order_id');
                $this->logger->addDebug(print_r( $orderId, true ));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We got this working.  The code in the `execute()` was all wrong.  Not sure why it didn't throw any errors, but its working.